# pdfHTML: Accessibility is not working properly with multiple tables which had heading converting html to pdf

Tags: java, pdf, accessibility, pdfhtml

I am new to IText and we have a requirement to convert the existing pdf's to accessibility. So we need to convert html to pdf using java. The html documents have multiple tables with headings in div structures. I had used the following example link (https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/pdfhtml-accessible-pdf-creation) to convert html to pdf. For content within the table, it reads fine in pdf. But the order is not working fine. Here is the sample html which I am referring to. If you read the load in Acrobat reader, it first reads the heading and then the content with in it. Can any one help in resolving the issue?

Below is the sample html which has multiple table via using a div structure:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Firtst table </h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Second  table </h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>2nd table Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>2nd table Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>2nd table Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>**
```

The above code has multiple tables which accessibility is not working with.

Comment: There are no tables in your HTML code. What you have are div elements containing headings and paragraphs made to look like tables using CSS. I'm not an iText user, but in any normal PDF conversion, this does not create a table.  You should inspect the PDF tags to see what structure is being generated during your conversion process.

Comment: That said, if your table is being used mostly for layout (i.e. not for tabular data), then you may be interested in layout table linearization concepts: https://webaim.org/techniques/tables/#linearization